# Can you migrate a "localhost" cloud to "public" cloud

Tags: juju

If you create a localhost cloud using juju, running kubernetes - is there a way to migrate to "public" cloud?

Answer (score 0):

### [**Migrating containers to Google Cloud: Migrating Kubernetes to GKE**](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/migrating-containers-kubernetes-gke)

This document helps you plan, design, and implement your migration from a self-managed Kubernetes environment to Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). If done incorrectly, moving apps from one environment to another can be a challenging task, so you need to plan and execute your migration carefully.

This document is part of a multi-part series about migrating to Google Cloud. If you're interested in an overview of the series, see Migration to Google Cloud: Choosing your migration path.

This document is part of a series that discusses migrating containers to Google Cloud:

- Migrating containers to Google Cloud: Getting started
- Migrating containers to Google Cloud: Migrating Kubernetes to GKE (this document)
- Migrating containers to Google Cloud: Migrating to a new GKE environment
- Migrating containers to Google Cloud: Migrating to a multi-cluster GKE environment with Multi Cluster Service Discovery and Multi Cluster Ingress
- Migrating containers to Google Cloud: Migrating from OpenShift to Anthos

This document is useful if you're planning to migrate from a self-managed Kubernetes environment to GKE. Your environment might be running in an on-premises environment, in a private hosting environment, or in another cloud provider. This document is also useful if you're evaluating the opportunity to migrate and want to explore what it might look like.

By using GKE, you get the following benefits:

- You don't have to manage control plane (master) nodes.
- You can use Google expertise for security, networking, Kubernetes upgrades, and node auto-provisioning.
- You can automatically scale your clusters by adding nodes or by tuning the CPU and memory request limits for Pods.

This document assumes that you have read and are familiar with the following tasks:

- Creating different types of GKE clusters
- Managing, configuring, and deploying GKE clusters
- Preparing a GKE environment for production
- Understanding GKE security
- Hardening your cluster's security

Migration path with four phases.

During each migration step, you follow the phases defined in Migration to Google Cloud: Getting started:

1. Assessing and discovering your workloads.
2. Planning and building a foundation.
3. Deploying your workloads.
4. Optimizing your environment.

I left you the reference as is mentioned this document is part of a multi-part series about migrating to Google Cloud.